# NullPointerException error in search through array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to run this code. It reads the file successfully, but breaks at the word search itself.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at WordSearch.main(WordSearch.java:30)
```

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class WordSearch{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    String searchWord, fileName; int i=0, j=0;

    fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of the file to be processes: ");
    File textFile = new File(fileName);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(textFile);

    String[] file = new String[500];
    String[] found = new String[500]; 

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        file[i]=scanner.next();
        i++;
    }

    file[i+1]="EoA"; i=0;

    searchWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input the string to search for: ");

    while(!file[i].equals("EoA")){
        if (file[i].equals(searchWord)){
            if(i==0){
                found[j]=file[i]+file[i+1]+"\n";
            }
            else if(i==500){
                found[j]=file[i-1]+file[i]+"\n";
            }
            else {
                found[j]=file[i-1]+file[i]+file[i+1]+"\n";
            }

            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, found);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
file[i+1]="EoA";
```

to

```
file[i]="EoA";
```

Otherwise, you'll have a null entry in the position that precedes the "EoA" entry, which causes the `NullPointerException`.

Of course, you can get rid of the "EoA" entry, and just change the loop's condition to :

```
while (file[i] != null)
```

That's much more readable.

One last thing, how do you guarantee that your input won't be larger than the 500 length of your array?

Comment: Thank you! Working with arrays and stuff in Java is really getting at me after having such an easy time in C :(

Comment: I'd use an ArrayList if I wanted the code to actually be practical.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your **i++** expression. In each iteration **i** is being incremented and the result gets stored in previous index pointed by the value of **i**

Possible solution is to use `i-1` in the **while** loop.